# WSO2 API Gateway convert JSON to JSON

Tags: json, api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need to configure JSON to JSON  transformations with API Manager 2.0 very efficiently.
By default, WSO2 API Manager makes transformations JSON-> XML-> and  after processing -> XML->JSON
I'd like to know how can I do so directly in JSON to reduce latencies.
Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

By default, APIM uses `PassThrough` transport which does not build your message unless it needs to access your message body. So, your json won't be converted to XML in that case.

For example, if you have configured [custom mediation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+Mediation+Extensions) and have a content-aware mediator like `<log level="full"/>`, APIM has to build (i.e. convert to XML) your message body so that it can log the entire message.

If you don't try to access the message body like that, json will be sent to backend as it is.